# BCELoss for binary pixel-wise segmentation pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm implementing a UNet for binary segmentation while using Sigmoid and BCELoss. The problem is that after several iterations the network tries to predict very small values per pixel  while for some regions it should predict values close to one (for ground truth mask region). Does it give any intuition about the wrong behavior?

Besides, there exist NLLLoss2d which is used for pixel-wise loss. Currently, I'm simply ignoring this and I'm using MSELoss() directly. Should I use NLLLoss2d with Sigmoid activation layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like that your Sigmoids are saturating the activation maps. The images are not properly normalised or some batch normalisation layers are missing. If you have an implementation that is working with other images check the image loader and make sure it does not saturate the pixel values. This usually happens with 16-bits channels. Can you share some of the input images?

PS Sorry for commenting in the answer. This is a new account and I am not allowed to comment yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Well, I'm using batchNormalization after in my networks, and RELU for all layers except the last one which is Sigmoid. What do you mean by "saturating pixel values" exactly?

Comment: 1. In this case, check if the output activation map is not too high or too low for the Sigmoid. The effective range is between ±sqrt(3).

2. RE: "saturating pixel values", PIL loader in pytorch sets all pixels to 1 for 16 bits images. I would suggest writing a little function that prints the pixel values and use it as a lambda transform. In this function, you will get the loaded image in the 1st parameter to check if the proper values have been loaded.

3. What are your normalisation parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`, replacing the Sigmoid and the BCELoss function.

An excerpt from the [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) tells you why its always better to use this loss function implementation.

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class. This version is more numerically stable than using a plain Sigmoid followed by a BCELoss as, by combining the operations into one layer, we take advantage of the log-sum-exp trick for numerical stability.